# Firebase dynamics's link

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Here is my base universal link `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/`, it used to be working properly but all of the sudden it stopped working. when I click on the link on Text message it opens up the safari and shows 400.That's an error. `The requested URL was not found on this server. That's all we know`.

Here is a dynamic link `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/KPoa` which was working before even it was installing the app if it wasn't installed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question doesn't really point at anything but a link that is not working. One can only assume things with the amount of information you have provided. Try adding more information and possible thoughts as to what you think is the problem.

Comment: Hey folks, why are you so quick at posting these negative comments? Can you imagine that this question is totally reasonable but you lacking context about Firebase Dynamic Links?

Answer (score 0):

The link `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl` is not an Firebase Dynamic Link. This is URL of your assigned domain in Firebase Dynamic Links.

You need to create dynamic link based on this domain. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links) about ways to create the link.

Your Firebase Dynamic Link should look like `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/xyzabcd`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That link actually is a base Universal  link which used to work and only open the app  or install the app. Here is one of the dynamic link that used to work `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/KPoa` but right now it does not open the app

Comment: Does not opens the App when App is already installed? 
BTW, your link do not have iOS parameters https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/KPoa?d=1 . This link should still engage iOS Universal Links.

Comment: This is showing my app is connected `https://k5j95.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association`. I am not sure what do you mean by iOS parameters on the link but I used to get a `venue Id` as a parameter from `FIRDynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()!.handleUniversalLink` in my `AppDelegate` when it was opening the app. If you click on `Your dynamic link` on the link you posted `k5j95.app.goo.gl/KPoa?d=1` then the redirected url shows the `id` for the `venue`.

Comment: iOS parameters meaning "dynamic link iOS parameters", see here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create , class FIRDynamicLinkIOSParameters. You will be able to specify those even you creating link from console/Android or REST API.
Please re-check that your AppPrefix id is LYUZH5XR59. Universal Links will not work if this value does not match. Also look online for guides of Universal Links troubleshooting. From your description it seems that Universal Links is not setup correctly.